# Multithreading c++ notify mechanism

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to multithreading Please help in understanding these basic concept. I will try to explain my question with the help of example.you can be brief but any comment will be appreciated. I am struggling a lot with this.

Note:
**condition for thread 2, 3 and 4 in condition variable is same for wait**.

Execution starts from Thread 1. Let's say currently Thread 1 is running and Thread 2, 3 and 4 are waiting on it to get lock. Once Thread 1 calls notify all Thread 2 successfully able to get lock.

1. why 2 will not need to notify here again as per my understanding because 3 and 4 might have gone again in wait condition since they failed to get the lock but there conditions were matching so they needs to be notified ?

Below program is from (program attached below)     https://cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/notify_all/

2. So here thread which is executing go function notify all one after that no other thread in print_id is notifying to subsequent thread in loops. simply it prints and next thread will automatically get locks. But how next threads were being waken up here. Or once go was executed it has called notify all then no thread will go to sleep again or waiting state.
3. when we called wait does thread go to sleep only if the condition is not met in condition variable if met for multiple threads they will remain in the execution queue ?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void print_id (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);
  // ...
  std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread threads[10];
  // spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(print_id,i);

  std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
  go();                       // go!

  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not write `while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);`. You should use `cv.wait(lck,[&]{return ready; };`. There is one basic rule with condition variables: never wait without predicates  because condition variables can 'spuriously wakeup` (wakeup without notify_one/notify_all being called)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that correctly prints your thread id's. It also shows you can easily package the condition_variable/mutex/state into one class for easy reuse and readability.

Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/vtFM-IfU7

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

// avoid globals as much as you can
// also makes later code more readable
class ready_signal_t
{
public:
    void set()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
        ready = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
        cv.wait(lock, [&] { return ready; });
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool ready = false;
};

//---------------------------------------------

class printer_t
{
public:
    void print_id(int id)
    {
        ready.wait();

        // "cleanup" output
        std::scoped_lock lock{print_mutex};
        std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
    }

    void go()
    {
        ready.set();
    }

private:
    ready_signal_t ready;
    std::mutex print_mutex;
};

int main()
{
    printer_t printer;

    std::array<std::thread, 10> threads;
    // spawn 10 threads:

    int id{ 0 };
    // prefer range based for loops
    for (auto& thread : threads)
    {
        // use lambda expression to start threads
        // it gives you fine control on how to pass
        // data to the threads.
        // the printer can be referenced. But the id must be copied
        thread = std::thread([&printer,id] { printer.print_id(id); });
        ++id;
    }

    std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
    printer.go();                       // go!

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```